# how can i get today's date in query builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i'm doing a project using laravel 5.3. I'm calling data from oracle database. how can i get today's date in query builder ?
for example:

```
$data=DB::connect('myoracle_db')->table('tablename')
->where('tablename.domain_label','=',$domain_name)
->update('tablename.domain_status'=>87)
->update('tablename.last_updated_date'=>'todaydate')
->paginate(5);
```

how can i get todays date in that query ? i know oracle must use to_date(sysdate) but i dont know how to convert it to query builder. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misleading title. I forgot to change it before posting it. I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a raw db expression with `DB::raw()` if you absolutely need to use Oracle instance's date

```php
DB::connect('myoracle_db')
    ->table('tablename')
    ->where('domain_label', $domain_name)
    ->update([
        'domain_status' => 87,
        'last_updated_date' => DB::raw('to_date(sysdate)'),
    ]);
```

On the other hand you can pass a date from the client (php) code:

```php
DB::connect('myoracle_db')
    ->table('tablename')
    ->where('domain_label', $domain_name)
    ->update([
        'domain_status' => 87,
        'last_updated_date' => Carbon\Carbon::today(),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
->update('tablename.last_updated_date'=>Carbon::now());
```

You need to import the namespace to use Carbon

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Comment: insert the use Carbon\Carbon; into the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple update(). Also you are not joining multiple tables, so you do not need to specifly tablename all the time.

```
->where('domain_label', '=', $domain_name)
->update([
    'domain_status' => 87,
    'last_updated_date' => date('Y-m-d') //if your column is datetime use 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
])
```